# Explicit Loading of OpenSSL libcrypto-1_1.dll Issues

Tags: delphi, openssl

I've been using older OpenSSL libeay32.dll via explicit loading (LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress) in Delphi 10.2. Now I want to switch to the newer libcrypto-1_1.dll (compiled from OpenSSL 1.1.1i). The function BIO_read in test code below works fine with the libeay32.dll (value returned in 'w' is 256), however it fails with libcrypto-1_1.dll (value returned in 'w' is -1 and ERR_get_error returns 0). However, if I try to load the libcrypto-1_1.dll implicitly, the code below works fine.

Any ideas what goes wrong here? Maybe Delphi does something special, when it loads the library, so I've tried to find the place in Delhi's source code where Delphi loads the dll, but I did not find it. Anyone knows in which unit Delphi handles the implicit loading?

```
procedute Test;
var sigLen,r,w:integer;
    base64Sig:TMemoryStream;
    mem,b64,bio:pBio;
    sig:pointer;
begin
  base64Sig:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  base64Sig.LoadFromFile(SignatureFileName);
  mem:=BIO_new(BIO_s_mem);
  b64:=BIO_new(BIO_f_base64);
  bio:=BIO_push(b64,mem);
  BIO_set_flags(b64,BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
  r:=BIO_write(mem,base64Sig.Memory,base64Sig.Size);
  writeln(r);
  GetMem(sig,sigLen);
  w:=BIO_read(b64,sig,sigLen);
  writeln(w);
end;
```

Comment: You should not use OpenSSL 0.9.8 which is know to have vulnerabilities and is out of support since 1st January 2016 and no longer receiving updates. At this time, you should use OpenSSL 1.1.1 and later.

Comment: You should probably remove the tags "linker", "loading" and "explicit".

Comment: I've removed tag 'linker'. Can I use space in tags (e.g. "explicit loading")? Also, the OpenSSL version was wrong, the correct version is 1.1.1i

Comment: You cannot really create new tags. Anyway, if you create one, there would be no listener and so it is not useful.

Comment: If you provide a signature file, I could check your code using ICS implementation of libcrypto-1_1.dll (http://wiki.overbyte.eu/wiki/index.php/ICS_Download).

Comment: `sigLen` is nowhere initialized.

Comment: Why don't people read compiler warnings?